# How to construct DTO object from controller

Tags: model-view-controller, repository, dto

I am using MVC pattern abstracted with domain layer. I could convert a domain object into its equivalent DTO and sending it across top layer (ie controller & ultimately to views). Now how to do the reverse? How & where will I construct the actual DTO object and pass it to the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the best way to do this is have a DTO service layer. This will be a collection of functions that the controller (or anything else) can call to retrieve and convert DTO's.

I would also recommend doing the domain object to DTO mapping (and the reverse) in this layer too, it keeps all the DTO related logic in one layer.

Below is an example of a DTO service layer function:

```
        public CustomerDto GetCustomer(Guid customerId) {

        var roService = new RoService<Customer>(new Repository<Customer>(_dbContextFactory));
        return _mapper.ToCustomerDto(roService.Get(customerId));
    }
```

This will retrieve a Customer entity by its Id. The entity is passed to a mapper object which will convert it to a CustomerDto for it to be returned.

N.B. I used AutoMapper to convert my domain objects to DTO's.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. However, how do we save or delete a customer in this case? I believe we will be calling roService.Save/Delete(customer). If it is so, where is this 'customer' object initialized? (Please forgive if it is a naive question, as am a newbie to both MVC and Repository pattern)

Comment: Yeah that's correct, you would call roService.Delete(customerId). Well, using this example you call .Get(customerId), that would return the required Customer object. Now we need to map that entity to a CustomerDto, this is done in some mapping class:

`public CustomerDto ToCustomerDto(Customer item)
        {
   return Mapper.Map<Customer, CustomerDto>(item);
        }`
That will return a new CustomerDto with all the fields mapped that you have defined. As I say, I personally used AutoMapper. I hope this helps.